# __strong or __weak (or something else) for parameter when overrideing -isEqual:?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm overriding `- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object` in a custom class.

Out of the 4 choices, which are `__weak`, `__strong`, `__autoreleasing`, and `__unsafe_unretained`, which should I be using on the parameter for the `isEqual:` method signature?

I'm thinking this is where the problem is, since when I'm trying to add an instance of my class to a `NSMutableDictionary`, I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x10)` at the declaration of the method.

In other words, the line at which the debugger gets the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id __strong)object {
```

before any of the method body is executed.

Comment: Any declaration of an Objective-C object reference type implicitly includes __strong, so I don't think you're problem is there. The function signature should remain the same as the function it's overriding. You are most likely passing a message to an object that was dealloc'ed or whose pointer is corrupt. I suggest running the Analyzer on your code and fixing any of the issues that are found.

Comment: Objects are strong by default. If you're getting bad access, then you're trying to read or write to an area that doesn't have what you think it has in it.

Comment: you were right. commenting out the function body and returning `NO` consistently made the error go away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was "If you're getting bad access, then you're trying to read or write to an area that doesn't have what you think it has in it.", per @Dustin Rowland in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ARC uses `__strong`, which means that the argument is held via a retain/release for the duration of its use inside the method. To lead to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, an object (either the argument itself, or any other object used in the method calls inside the `isEqual:` implementation) has to be over-released when accessing it. This cannot be fixed by changing the qualifier.

Sidenote: Be careful though by expecting to see anything to change when you change the qualifier. The compiler optimizations may decide that it is safe to skip some calls. For example, add the following code to a file and look at the assembly (Product -> Generate Output -> Assembly File) for Archiving (which uses -Os).

```
- (void)logObject:(id)o
{
    NSLog(@"%@", o);
}

- (void)call
{
    id o = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    [self logObject:o];
}
```

Although the parameter of `logObject:` is the default `__strong`, no retain/release is done in the assembly output. Changing the parameter of `-logObject:` to `__strong`, `__weak`, `__unsafe_unretained` or `__autoreleasing` gives exactly the same assembly output. If you duplicate the line with the `NSLog` however, the assembly code changes for the different type qualifiers.

Comment: This is an interesting phenomenon, but I wouldn't quite arrive to that conclusion based on the assembly file. Isn't it possible that the -retain: and -release: calls aren't added by the pre-processor unless they are necessary? At least, that's how I imagine ARC would work.

Comment: @ryanrhee90 As an example, take `__autoreleasing` which should always add the object to the autorelease pool. It does happen for local variables, it does not happen for parameters.

Comment: @ryanhee90 I re-checked with a more complex example, and you are right: there `__strong`, `__weak` and `__unsafe_unretained` make a difference. I could not come up with any example where `__autoreleasing` made any difference.